# Excel VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH with Multiple Criteria and Date Range

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, vlookup

I have been struggling to solve this for a couple of days.

I tried some VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH with multiple criteria but it doesn't work.

=VLOOKUP(TABLE 2B2&C2,TABLE 1 B:D,3,TRUE)

I have table 1, that is an historic report with a date stamped when the status was changed from one to another for several accounts.

On table 2, I would need to populate the third column with a formula that would return the stage on that date.

e.g.

On the 22/04 when a task was created for Apple the stage was in Pipeline

| Account Name | Edit Date | Old Value | New Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 19/04/2021 | Prospect | In Pipeline |
| Apple | 01/06/2021 | In Pipeline | Customer |

Table 2

| Account Name | Created Date | FORMULA with MATCH RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 22/04/2021 | In Pipeline |
| Apple | 01/07/2021 | Customer |

Many thanks for your help on this!

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: Hello Scott, I have version 16.62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FILTER()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759):

```
=FILTER(D:D,(B:B=MAXIFS(B:B,B:B,"<"&H2,A:A,G2))*(A:A=G2),"")
```

There are two booleans `(B:B=MAXIFS(B:B,B:B,"<"&H2,A:A,G2))` which returns the latest date that happened prior to the reference date and `(A:A=G2)` that returns those that match the Account Name.

[image]

---

### NOTE:

<sub>I have used full column references here just to help simplify the example.  In real use, one should limit the ranges to that of the size of the data.  Otherwise this one formula will do millions of calculations and the use over a larger dataset will start to slow the calculations.</sub>

Comment: That's incredible! thank you so much, I never used this type of formula. I have 8000 rows on table 1 and around 40000 on the second one. I hope it will work fine.

Comment: It will as long as you limit the references to the the data set and not use full column references.

Comment: Thank again! Have a diet coke on me :)